# EJB Remote Exception handling

Tags: exception, ejb, rmi, oc4j

I've a Remote `SLSB` that is deployed in `OC4J`.

This Session Bean uses TopLink which under some case throws `oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.QueryException` exception.

I am handling this exception this way:

```
public void slsbMethod()
{
   try
   {
      // oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.QueryException throws here 
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {
      // do nothing
   }
}
```

And I am calling this SLSB from a client that way:

```
try
{
    fooBarService.slsbMethod()
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("Exception calling the EJB server");
}
```

However I am handling this exception on the EJB, still I got the message `Exception calling the EJB server` printed!

How is this happening??

Comment: What is the exception stack trace for the error?  Are you sure the exception is being thrown from within your method and not from the container-managed transaction code in the EJB container?

Comment: Yes you are right, it might be thrown from the container-managed transaction code in the EJB container, So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exception is coming from container-managed transaction code, then I would suggest using bean-managed transactions.  With that, you can put the exception handling in the bean around the call to UserTransaction.commit.  Alternatively, you could write an interceptor to begin the transaction, call InvocationContext.proceed(), and then commit the transaction and handle exceptions as you like.  This is basically what the container is doing for you, but you can handle the commit exception as you like, and you can reuse the logic on other beans/methods.